# Finite distribution of a homogeneous Poisson point process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I need help to find the finite distribution (fidi) of a homogeneous Poisson point process for overlapping set. For example:

Let $\Phi$ be a uniform Poisson point process of intensity $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$. I want to determine $\mathbb{P}(\Phi(B_1) = n_1, \Phi(B_2) = n_2)$ for $B_1 = [0,2]$ and $B_2 = [1,3]$. Here, $n_1$ and $n_2$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: What if you define the disjoint sets $E,F,G$ by $E=B_1 \cap B_2^c$, $F=B_1\cap B_2$, $G=B_2 \cap B_1^c$?  For this example, that is $E=[0,1)$, $F=[1,2]$, $G=(2,3]$.

Comment: What if? Well, then, problem solved.